# Наследование приватных полей python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, наследование

У меня есть класс-родитель `Time` с приватными полями, с которыми в классе-потомке нужно вывести строку. Однако программа не работает - после введения значений появляется ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'Train' object has no attribute '_Train__h'. Did you mean '_Train__num'?

Если посмотреть на экземпляр с помощью `print(result.__dict__)`, то станет видно, что все поля родительского класса выглядят так: `_Time__h`, `_Time__m`, `_Time__s`, тогда как поле класса-наследника выглядят так: `_Train__num`. Я так поняла, что именно поэтому программа и не работает, так как считает, что поля времени принадлежат классу-родителю, а в классе-потомке их нет. Что именно я делаю не так?

```
# Родитель - Время (три числа): часы h, минуты m, секунды s
class Time:
    def __init__(self, h = 0, m = 0, s = 0):
        self.__h = h
        self.__m = m
        self.__s = s

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Time: {self.h:02}:{self.m:02}:{self.s:02}"
        
    def set_h(self, h):
        self.__h = h
    def set_m(self, m):
        self.__m = m
    def set_s(self, s):
        self.__s = s

    def get_h(self):
        return self.__h
    def get_m(self):
        return self.__m
    def get_s(self):
        return self.__s


# Потомок - Время отправления поезда - номер поезда num, время отправления (от родителя)
class Train(Time):
    def __init__(self, h = 0, m = 0, s = 0, num = 'No'):
        super().__init__(h, m, s)
        self.__num = num

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Time: {self.__h:02}:{self.__m:02}:{self.__s:02}\nTrain number: {self.__num}"
        
    def set_num(self, num):
        self.__num = num

    def get_num(self):
        return self.__num

result = Train()
h, m, s = map(int, (input('Enter hours: ', ), input('Enter minutes: ', ), input('Enter seconds: ', )))
num = input('Train number: ', )

print(result)
```

Comment: Приватное поле не предназначено для использования в наследниках. Оно приватное, оно только для родителя. В потомке используйте `get_*`.

Comment: Можете пояснить подробнее, что Вы имеете в виду (я про get_*)? То есть, как это будет примерно выглядеть в коде и как называется, так как, боюсь, что такого я не учила.

Comment: В родителе объявлен метод `def get_h(self):`.  Вы сумеете его вызвать в потомке? Что получится если вы его   вызовете?

Comment: используйте `_name` вместо `__name`, если хотите наследовать поля. насчет дубликата сомневаюсь, но вот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504889/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/1504950#1504950), на который уже давали [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1504950/368899).

Comment: Если добавить set и get в класс-потомок, то ничего не изменится. Правда, может, нужно их как-то изменить при добавлении в класс-потомок? Я в этом не очень хорошо разбираюсь
    `def set_h(self, h):
        self.__h = h
    def set_m(self, m):
        self.__m = m
    def set_s(self, s):
        self.__s = s
    
    def get_h(self):
        return self.__h
    def get_m(self):
        return self.__m
    def get_s(self):
        return self.__s`

Или же я видела, что иногда в этом случае используют защищенные поля. Может ли это считаться приватностью?

Comment: @n1tr0xs
Спасибо, если ничего не сработает, то использую этот способ. С ним все работает, я уже проверяла до этого.